# How do I block TCP ACK causing retransmissions

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, amazon-s3

I am trying to replicate a issue when making requests to S3 that will lead to tcp_retries2 leading to 900 seconds of retransmission attempts before giving up. How would I do this? Is it sufficient to block incoming requests via iptables from the s3 endpoint on my client host?